# Mac OSX n00b: what is a .login file?

Tags: macos, sh

Firstly, I'm using Mac OS X. Secondly, I am attempting to install something which says:

> If you include this line (or source `$CALDB/software/tools/caldbinit.sh`
>   for Bourne shell users) in your `.login` file, then the CALDB will be
>   available to you every time you log in.

What exactly is the .login file? And where can it be found?

Comment: It's in your home directory (`$HOME` or `~`). But `.login` is specific to the `csh` or `tcsh` shell. If you're using `sh` or some shell derived from it (`ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`), then `.login` will be ignored. For `bash`, use `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @KeithThompson It would be useful if you didn't neglect to say that .bash_profile is a hidden file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *nix systems, each time you login, it looks for a file named .login and executes any commands it finds in the file. Much like when you start a new C shell, the system looks for a file named .cshrc and executes it.

Though OSX uses [other ways](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) to implement this functionality, .login is still recognized. Typically .login file includes a command to "source" (read and execute) a standard system login file that sets the standard PATH, TERM, and PROMPT variables. Others such as your CALDB installation want to be initialized at login time by inserting the appropriate source line:

```
source $CALDB/software/tools/caldbinit.sh
```

Note you may have to substitute the literal path for $CALDB in the path above  since that var may not be initialized at the time of login when this script is run.

Addendum:

.login is typically in the home directory when using csh or tsch shells. If it's not there, you'll have to create it. However, depending on the version of OSX you are using you may have other options or different ways of achieving the same effect. Follow the documentation (link provided above) for the best option for your version of OS X.

Comment: And where can this file be found exactly? I understand what you are saying, that I need the above line in the .login file....but my problem is that I don't have one/can't find one!

Comment: Only `csh` and `tcsh` pay attention to the `.login` file. sh-derived shells, including `bash`, do not use it.

Comment: @user3125347, added addendum to the response.

Comment: And how do we create it?